# Next js 404 page doesn't work. What could be the problem?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, production

When I try to go on a non-existing route, always load the home page but the URL doesn't change. I expected to receive a 404 page.

I create a custom error page `pages/_error.js`

```
import Page404 from './404';

function Error({ statusCode }) {
  return statusCode ? (
    <p>{`An error ${statusCode} occurred on server`}</p>
  ) : (
    <Page404 />
  );
}

Error.getInitialProps = ({ res, err }) => {
  const statusCode = res ? res.statusCode : err ? err.statusCode : 404;
  return { statusCode };
};

export default Error;
```

Tell me please, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The error page is only used in production and not development. Thats probably causing this issue.

Comment: In development, everything works fine. it's a matter of production all the routes to be led on the 404 go to the home page and the URL doesn't change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. In `nginx.conf` I find following line `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;` and change `/index.html` to `/404/index.html` it's helped. But i dont know if this a good solution.